# Set interval for RetinaJS

Tags: setinterval, retina.js

I already have setInterval for the images changing on my website. My problem is that it is only the first image that is replaced with the retina image. How can I load my retina.js again when the other images is loaded? They are changing every 5 sec

I use the script from retinajs.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using CSS media queries you can serve these high–resolution images automatically to retina devices.

```
 /*CSS for basic styling and non-retina image path:*/
    .icon{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-image: url(icon.png);
    }
    /*CSS for serving the retina image to devices with a high "device-pixel-ratio":*/
    @media only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (min-devicepixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (min-resolution: 1.5dppx) {
        .icon{
            background-image: url(icon@2x.png);
            background-size: 100px 100px;
        }
    }
```

UPDATED:
 - Cons(retina.js): If you are using retina.js you are serving
   normal-sized and @2x images to retina devices, which dramatically
   increases the loading time of your site. I cannot recommend using
   retina.js if you care about a fast loading time.
 - CSS media query (Pros): By adding a CSS media query that detects
   high-definition displays you can change the image path of the
   original background-image to the @2x image for those displays.

Update:

You might need to modify retina.js to work in slideshows.(See here https://github.com/imulus/retinajs/pull/26)

Modifying these lines

```
that.el.setAttribute('width', that.el.offsetWidth);
that.el.setAttribute('height', that.el.offsetHeight);
```

to this..

```
 if(that.el.hasAttribute('width')){
    that.el.setAttribute('width', that.el.offsetWidth);}
  if(that.el.hasAttribute('height')){
    that.el.setAttribute('height', that.el.offsetHeight);}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is it necessary to change the retina script? Is the CSS solution better?

Comment: If you are using retina.js you are serving normal-sized and @2x images to retina devices, which dramatically increases the loading time of your site. I cannot recommend using retina.js if you care about a fast loading time.

Comment: Tried to do it the way you suggested. I'm a photographer so it is really important to me that the images are as sharp as possible. So this downscaling method wont work. I don't mind the loading time if I get better quality images.

Comment: @user2980817 You need to modify the retina.js..See this https://github.com/imulus/retinajs/pull/26

Comment: thank you so much for the answer. Can't seem to figure it out. It might be a little bit easier if I just link the website – see this http://oscarmeyer.dk/test/